# Spring validation: can't convert from String to Date

Tags: spring, hibernate-validator

I'm doing some spring form validation, however I'm getting:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'ja
va.util.Date' for property 'birthdate'; nested exception is java.lang.Illega
lStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required typ
e [java.util.Date] for property 'birthdate': no matching editors or conversi
on strategy found
```

However, in my modelAttribute form I have:

```
@NotNull
 @Past
 @DateTimeFormat(style="S-")
 private Date birthdate;
```

I thought the DateTimeFormat was responsible for this?

I'm using the hibernate-validator 4.0.

Comment: Do you have `<mvc:annotation-driven>`?

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is in a portlet so the mvc:annotation-driven doesn't work. I use: <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
 
 <bean id="annotationMethodHandlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
     <property name="webBindingInitializer">
         <bean id="configurableWebBindingInitializer" class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
             <property name="validator">
                 <ref bean="validator"/>

Comment: </property>
         </bean>
     </property>
 </bean>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Theres a chance you'll have to use register a `CustomDateEditor` in your controller(s) to convert from a String to a Date. The example method below goes in your controller, but you'll have to change the date format to match whatever you're using.

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"), true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to use `@DateTimeFormat` you need to install `FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean`. `<mvc:annotation-driven>` does it implicitly, but if you cannot use it you need something like this:

```
<bean id="conversionService" 
    class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" /> 

<bean id="annotationMethodHandlerAdapter"    
    class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"> 
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean id="configurableWebBindingInitializer"
            class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer"> 
            <property name="validator"><ref bean="validator"/>
            <proeprty name = "conversionService" ref = "conversionService" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```